# 2 finger right click Macbook 4.1 with Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: touchpad, macbook

I've installed 18.04 on an Old MacBook 4.1 All working fine except for two finger right click. I can 2 finger scroll and can left click. Right click is possible with ctrl and Click, but i'd really like to use two finger and click for right click. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Install Gnome Tweak tool using the command below:

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
```

Then check the keyboard and mouse settings:
[image]